leaving and causing referring?
In tinea capitis the fungus invades the hair shafts, causing the hairs to become brittle and to break off at the level of the scalp, leaving an area of stubby, black dotted alopecia.
Hello, is the “leaving” participle in this sentence referring to “hair” or “fungus”? I thought of it like this :
In tinea capitis the fungus invades the hair shafts and ( fungus ) causes the hairs to become brittle and to break off at the level of the scalp and (fungus) leaves an area of stubby, black dotted alopecia.

The fact that the fungus invades the hair shafts causes the hair to become brittle. The fact that the hairs break off leaves an area of alopecia.

Then the subject of “leaving” is “hair”?

So we're supposed to think of it like this :  In tinea capitis the fungus invades the hair shafts, causing the hairs to become brittle and to break off at the level of the scalp AND causing the hairs to become brittle and to break off at the level of the scalp, leaving an area of stubby, black dotted alopecia ? like two separate subjects of two separate sentences. It's a bit weird.

Why do you repeat  causing the hairs to become brittle and to break off at the level of the scalp? What leaves the bald area is the breaking-off of the hairs.

You'd be better off working with your own stuff and not relying on ChatGPT. Kate answers this very concisely so why is there all this palavering? :) The lawn mower cut the grass very well, leaving a green, verdant lawn.

What’s leaving the area of alopecia is the breaking off. Here you can think of the word leaving as performing exactly the same function, and with the exact same meaning as which leaves.

I'm sure you're right, but I can't help thinking it might be possible to construct an utterance with the same basic pattern where the final "outcome" clause attached to the same initial "action causing effect" as another (immediately preceding) outcome clause, rather than "chaining" cause + effect1 so that effect1 leads to effect2. That's to say, I'm not convinced the syntax itself unambiguously forces one single interpretation, if that conflicts with logic. That would certainly happen if we precede leaving by and, but maybe also even without.

ChatGPT said :  The fungus invades the hair shafts.
The hairs become brittle and break off at the level of the scalp.
The breaking off of the hairs in this way leaves a stubby, black-dotted area of alopecia.
So, "leaving" describes the resultant state of the hairs. This is why in the sentence structure, "leaving" directly refers to the "hair".

it also said that this is also true: "Leaving" word refers both to "fungus" and "hair" in the sentence structure.

what are your thoughts ?

My general thought is that this is but the latest illustration that Chat GPT is not to be trusted as a style reference. A verb in English cannot have two subjects (though it can certainly have a single subject that is compound: Mary and I are friends), so ChatGPT is wrong about the syntax. And it’s nonsensical to say that hair leaves alopecia, so ChatGPT is wrong about the logic too.

but I was the one who pushed chatgpt to say the second one. Actually, chatgpt insisted on the first thing I said.

Ok, but even if it hadn’t offered an opinion until you solicited one, the opinion that it apparently did then offer is wrong.

leaving doesn't "refer" to anything, pace ChatGPT. The two participial clauses, one headed by causing the other by leaving, are coordinated asyndetically instead of syndetically by and. Both clauses stand in relation to the main clause.
Compare:

His egg-timer failed to ding, causing his three-minute egg to be a nine-minute egg, leaving him with a choice: eat the hardboiled egg for breakfast or take it with him to work and have it for lunch.
His egg-timer failed to ding, causing his three-minute egg to be a nine-minute egg and leaving him with a choice: eat the hardboiled egg for breakfast or take it with him to work and have it for lunch.

There are more details provided in the causing clause that shed light on the leaving clause, but syntactically the leaving clause hinges on  the main clause. I don't think  the leaving clause is a relative clause as it has no noun antecedent as "trains arriving at the station" does.

Come on, for something like this your downvote needs an explanation.

In the example you gave, I considered the sentence “His egg-timer failed to ding” as the common subject of causing and leaving.

so we can actually think like this : His egg-timer failed to ding and this caused his three-minute egg to be a nine-minute egg and this left him with a choice:

@emilywenly You are contradicting yourself. In your first comment you say the main clause is "the common subject of causing and leaving" but in your second comment you have the clause headed by causing acting as the subject of the clause headed by leaving:  "this caused his three-minute egg to be a nine-minute egg and this left him with a choice..."     In my answer I have the two  participial clauses as coordinated, and both hinge on the main clause, not the one on the other.  So I agree with your first comment but not your second.

Perhaps I should say that you seem to have the causing clause acting as the subject of the leaving clause. since your use of the pronoun this is not perfectly clear.

I'm sorry, my mistake, I misunderstood. So even if there are two participles in such sentences, we will relate both sentences to the main sentence by looking at the context of the sentence, right?

On a semantic level it is a kind of catenation: medical condition => effects of that condition on the hair => appearance those effects produce. I believe you understand the meaning. But treating the leaving clause as a relative clause is not, I think, the right way to understand it. You don't need to relate the clause back to a particular antecedent noun, hair or fungus, as you ask in your question.
